# Pandas changing the data type of column from float to integer when I did not ask for it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am bit puzzled of what is happening here. I have a method that takes values from one pandas dataframe and creates a new one. There are columns that are only strings, floats or ints. The method works fine and creates new dataframe where the datatypes do not change, expect for one column,where for some reason it gives only int part of the number. I cannot see why specifically that column. My method looks like this:

```
def assignPropsToFinList(self,gensodLays):
    updtZbotmDf=pd.DataFrame({"ZBOTM (m)":gensodLays})
    columnTitle = self.soilDf.columns.tolist()
    for i in range(len(columnTitle)):
        if i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            updtZbotmDf[columnTitle[i]] = 0
            for j in range(len(gensodLays)):
                for k in range(len(self.soilDf)):
                    if j == 0 and k == 0:
                        updtZbotmDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][j] = self.soilDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][k]
                    elif updtZbotmDf["ZBOTM (m)"][j] == self.soilDf["Penetration (m)"][k] and updtZbotmDf["ZBOTM (m)"][j] == \
                            self.soilDf["Penetration (m)"][k - 1]:                                                   # here I am sorting the points that where onee layer ends and other starts and both have same depth value
                        updtZbotmDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][j] = self.soilDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][k - 1]
                    elif updtZbotmDf["ZBOTM (m)"][j] == self.soilDf["Penetration (m)"][k] and updtZbotmDf["ZBOTM (m)"][j] != \
                            self.soilDf["Penetration (m)"][k - 1]:
                        updtZbotmDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][j] = self.soilDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][k]
                    elif self.soilDf["Penetration (m)"][k] > updtZbotmDf["ZBOTM (m)"][j] > self.soilDf["Penetration (m)"][k - 1]:
                        updtZbotmDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][j] = self.soilDf.loc[:, (columnTitle[i])][k]
    return updtZbotmDf
```

The only specific thing about the column where the values are changed for some reason from float to int is that it consists both ints and floats, as well it goes right affter the column that has only string values

Comment: You're making us work hard to help you.

Comment: Can you trim your code to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I guess code is as trimmed as it could be, but just to explain briefly what my problem is that: I have for example first column - that has floats when I create new data frame datatype remains the same, I have second column that are strings and when I create new dataframe with same column string remains string, I have third column that has as a input mix of floats and ints and when I create new dataframe it becomes only int (which is the part I do not get). .

Comment: Finally, after that I have bunch of other columns where initial dataframe has float and then values in new dataframe are floats which is all good. Personally, in my method I cannot see anything where I am manipulating datatypes, my code is simply just a logic to extract specific values from original dataframe

Answer (score 0):

How about you give this a try

```
updtZbotmDf=pd.DataFrame({"ZBOTM (m)":gensodLays},dtype=str)
```